# Sacar el max de una columna segun el max de otra SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tengo una consulta donde tengo que hacer un select que me de el máximo de una columna dependiendo del máximo de otra, me explico mejor con el siguiente ejemplo

mi tabla seria asi:

```
|nrocon|ordren|ordamp|
|  1   |  1   |  0   |
|  1   |  1   |  1   |
|  1   |  1   |  2   |
|  1   |  1   |  3   |
|  1   |  2   |  0   |
|  1   |  2   |  1   |
|  1   |  2   |  2   |
|  1   |  3   |  0   |
|  1   |  3   |  1   |
|  2   |  1   |  0   |
|  2   |  2   |  0   |
|  2   |  2   |  1   |
|  2   |  2   |  2   |
|  3   |  1   |  0   |
|  3   |  1   |  1   |
```

Entonces, yo lo que necesitaria es que al hacer el select me diera los siguientes datos:

```
|nrocon|ordren|ordamp|
|  1   |  3   |  1   |
|  2   |  2   |  2   |
|  3   |  1   |  1   |
```

O sea seria el máximo ordamp de el máximo ordren de cada nrocon.

Si alguno me podría dar una mano de como lo podría hacer se lo agradecería

Probe con la siguiente:

```
select NroCon, max(ordren), max(ordamp) from Polizas
group by NroCon
```

Pero con esta la tabla me queda asi:

```
|nrocon|ordren|ordamp|
|  1   |  3   |  3   |
|  2   |  2   |  2   |
|  3   |  1   |  1   |
```

en este ejemplo la diferencia seria en el nrocon 1, que al ordamp le pone 3 en vez de 1 que es el maximo de el ordren 3. espero con esto me entiendan mejor

Comment: Bievenido para entender mejor la pregunta editala y coloca el la consulta que hayas probado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te entendí correctamente, una forma de resolverlo es la siguiente:

```
select  A.NroCon,
    A.max_ordren,
    B.max_ordamp
    from (select    NroCon, 
            max(ordren) max_ordren
            from Polizas
            group by NroCon
    ) A
    inner join (select  NroCon, 
                ordren, 
                max(ordamp) max_ordamp
                from Polizas
                group by NroCon,ordren
        ) B
        ON A.NroCon = B.NroCon
        AND A.max_ordren = B.ordren
```

- En la subconsulta B obtenemos los valores máximos de `ordamp` por cada `NroCon` y `ordren`
- Luego, en A, solo necesitamos obtener los valores máximos pero de `ordren` por  `NroCon`
- Luego sencillamente hacemos un `JOIN` de estas dos consultas.

Comment: Buenisimo me funciono era esto lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

no se si entendi bien tu pregunta, pero segun lo que veo seria un Group by sencillo con dos Max de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT nrocon,MAX(ordren),MAX(ordamp) FROM [TuTabla]
GROUP BY nrocon
```

Verifica por favor y comenta si es lo que necesitas.
Un feliz día.

Comment: Ahí recién lo edite justamente con esa misma consulta que es la que yo había probado, y de esa forma no lo hace como necesito que lo haga.
Gracias igual, y un feliz dia para vos.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.nrocon,t1.ordren,max(t1.ordamp) as ordamp
from Tabla t1
where t1.ordren = (select max(t2.ordren) from Tabla t2 where t2.nrocon = t1.nrocon)
group by t1.nrocon,t1.ordren
```

Comment: Hola HeavyXABY, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio). Aunque esta respuesta puede ser útil y servir para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por su extensión y contenido. Edítala para añadir una descripción de lo que hace el código y por qué solucionaría el problema. Lee [answer] para más información. Saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)